# How can I semi-automatically mount a TrueCrypt volume using built in system tools?

Tags: fedora, automounting, truecrypt

I recently purchased a new external hard drive and encrypted it with TrueCrypt as I want it accessible from both Windows and Linux. However, when I try to access the mount point for it in Linux it hangs indefinitely unless I previously load the volume with cryptsetup. So I'm guessing the problem is in my crypttab. Here's the line for the volume:

```
USBMassStorageTB /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:14.0-usb-0\:3\:1.0-scsi-0\:0\:0\:0-part1 none tcrypt,noauto
```

The goal with that is to create an entry called /dev/mapper/USBMassStorageTB at the disk with that path, prompting for a password rather than reading it from a file, using truecrypt and not automounting at boot.

My understanding - which may be flawed - of what should happen is:

1. I access the mountpoint
2. System sees this is not mounted, and looks it up in fstab
3. System finds the entry in fstab pointing at device /dev/mapper/USBMassStorageTB and looks for that device, loading it if it's available (so far so good - this works fine if the device is opened with cryptsetup)
4. If the device is not available, it needs to be decrypted based on the settings in crypttab - this is the bit where I'm not clear on what happens, I'm assuming it just looks up the entry for /dev/mapper/USBMassStorageTB in crypttab and sees it needs to decrypt the volume at that path
5. The now-decrypted volume has a device entry and gets mounted according to the settings in fstab, and I can access the volume

The most useful information I've obtained so far is from the ArchWiki TrueCrypt page, specifically the automounting section at

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Automounting_using_.2Fetc.2Fcrypttab

which seems to imply the fstab and crypttab settings I have should be sufficient.